# "export" gets converted to "export default" preventing import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a library with TypeScript and Parcel. Everything's fine until i try to import it in another app.

In the library is a `index.ts` file which gathers the components and exports them:

```
import Component1 from "./components/Component1";
import Component2 from './components/Component2';

export {
    Component1,
    Component2,
};
```

After building i get `index.js`, `index.css` and `index.d.ts`.
In the `index.d.ts` file the `export` has been converted to `export default`:

```
export default Component1;
export default Component2;
```

I linked my library with yarn to my consumer app. When i want to `import { Component1 } from 'myLibrary';` i get the following error: `Module '"myLibrary"' has no exported member 'Component1'. Did you mean to use 'import Component1 from "myLibrary"' instead?`.  Now when i try to import default (like it is in the `index.d.ts`) `import Component1 from 'myLibrary';` the error changes to: `Attempted import error: 'myLibrary' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Component1').`

Why does the `export` conversion happen and how can i circumvent this?

EDIT:
The Library gets built and bundled by parcel, the consumer gets handled by react-scripts.
After Mr.Manhattans suggestion:

index.ts:

```
export {Component1} from "./components/Component1";
export {Component2} from './components/Component2';
```

generated index.d.ts:

```
export {Component1} from "./components/Component1";
export {Component2} from './components/Component2';
```

consumer:

```
function App() => {
    render(
        <>
            <Component1 />
            <Component2 />
        </>
    )
};
```

Error:

```
./src/App.tsx
[1] Attempted import error: 'Component2' is not exported from 'myLibrary'.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can direcly export:

```
export Component1 from "./components/Component1";
export Component2 from './components/Component2';
```

Comment: This results again in `Attempted import error: 'Footer' is not exported from 'samoa_pwa'.`

Comment: Sounds like a different (new) error that is revealed after you fixed the first one. Can you share a full repro?

Comment: Did add the new files for the error.

Comment: Hmm the generated index.d.ts does look correct now. i don't have experience with building react libraries. is the package.json specifying the index files (`"main": "index.js", "module": "index.esm.js", "types": "index.d.ts",` and also pointing to this exact index.ts file?

Comment: since i have no knowledge here, i was looking at how it's done in https://github.com/sixfootsixdesigns/React-Library-Boilerplate, maybe you can compare that to what you have and find mistakes there?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to re-export a named export that doesn't exist. Try re-exporting the default instead:

```js
export { default as Component1 } from './components/Component1';
export { default as Component2 } from './components/Component2';
```